# Calling variable from external file multiple times in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I'm trying to call variable from external file. And for that I wrote this code,

```
count = 1
while (count <= 3):
   # I want to iterate this line
   # rand_gen is the python file
   # A is the varialbe in rand_gen.py
   # Having this expression A = np.random.randint(1, 100)
   from rand_gen import A

   print('Random number is ' + str(A))
   count = count + 1
```

But when I run my code it only calls varible `A` once and prints the same result. See the output of code,

```
Random number is 48
Random number is 48
Random number is 48
```

How can I call variable `A` from file `rand_gen.py` with updated value, every time it goes into loop? Please help.

Comment: Reading the value `A` doesn't change the value, it was assigned the first time you loaded the module. Why aren't you just calling `np.random.randint(1, 100)`. You can force it but it is very unintuitive, e.g. `import importlib; importlib.reload(rand_gen)`

Comment: Alternatively, make `A` a function and call it, e.g. `def A(): return np.random.randint(1, 100)` then `str(A())` will give you a different value each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how `import` works in python. Once imported, `module` in cached in `sys.modules` as `key`, `value` pair of module name and module object. When you try to import the same `module` again, you simply get the already cached value back. But `sys.modules` is writable and deleting `the` key will, cause `python` to check for module and load again.

Though Olivier's answer is the right way to approach this, for your understanding of `import`, you can try this:

```
import sys       # Import sys module

count = 1
while (count <= 3):
   # I want to iterate this line
   # rand_gen is the python file
   # A is the varialbe in rand_gen.py
   # Having this expression A = np.random.randint(1, 100)
   if 'rand_gen' in sys.modules:   # Check if "rand_gen" is cached
       sys.modules.pop('my_rand')  # If yes, remove it
   from my_rand import A           # Import now

   print('Random number is ' + str(A))
   count = count + 1
```

**Output**

```
Random number is 6754
Random number is 963
Random number is 8825
```

Would recommend to read official Python docs on [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [The module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache), for thorough understanding.

Comment: Thank you @akshat this is what I want. Because my actual code is different and this method works for that. Thank you again.

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

If you assign a random value to a variable, referencing that variable does not make the value change regardless of how the value was obtained.

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 100)

a # 12
# Wait a little
a # still 12
```

In the same way, when you imported your module, the module code was execute and a value was assigned to `A`. Unless the module is reloaded with `importlib.reload` or you call `np.random.randint` again, there is no reason for `A` to change value.

What you might want is to make `A` a function that returns a random value in the desired range.

```
# In the rand_gen module
def A():
    return np.random.randint(1, 100)
```